# Simple Failover dual homing setup

Tags: networking, routing, isp, ipv4, multi-homed

I have a **50Mbps** fiber connection, and it has daily downtime of 10%.
The connection is down, exactly when I start to do something important.

Also, I have a **4G** connection with 4GB/day limit and weekend rollover.

I am thinking about having a failover setup, in which, all my devices will be connected to a **single wi-fi** network, and when the fiber link gets down, the router/gateway device automatically switched to 4G and I get partially-interrupted internet connectivity.

I have a private VPS, and I can use it for VPN, for a complete failover - in which my public IP address will remain same, even when my connection has been modified.

I have a **D-Link DIR-615** wifi router (a very basic one) and I have **Raspberry Pi 3B+**. I can buy stuff if needed, if the total cost is less than **$20-$30 in INDIA**.

Can anybody suggest how do I achieve this, or if it is even possible.

Comment: There was somewhat similar question recently, so I ask you too: are you sure it is fiber connection down or does your router reboot at that time and you have no LAN connection as well? There are different solutions depending whether it is a router issue or just connection issue.

Comment: This is a FAQ. Have you searched for similar questions?

Comment: I am 100% sure the fiber connection is down. I have already searched for similar questions.